# If the nilpotent class of $G$ is $k$, what's the nilpotent class of $G/C_{k-1}(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I read from a website, it said the nilpotent class will be $k-1$ at most. But why? (I know as the quotient group its class should be $k$ at most.)

Comment: What is $C_{k-1}(G)$?

Comment: Thank you, The definition is here:Set $C_0(G)$ = G and inductively define Ci+1(G) = [Ci(G), G].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $C_i(G)$ is called the *lower central series* of $G$ (although it is more standard for it to start with $C_1(G)=G$). It has the property  that if

$$G=G_0 > G_1 > G_2 > \cdots $$

is any central series of $G$, then $C_i(G) \le G_i$ for all $i$. This is straightforward to prove by induction on $i$.

So is $G$ is nilpotent of class $n$ then, by definition, it has a central series of length $n$ (i.e. $G_{n}=1$), but none of length $n-1$. So $C_n(G) \le G_n=1$, but we cannot have $C_{n-1}(G)=1$, or else $G$ would have class less than $n$.

Now $$G/C_{n-1}(G) = C_0(G)/C_{n-1}(G) > C_1(G)/C_{n-1}(G) > \cdots > C_{n-1}(G)/C_{n-1}(G)$$
is the lower central series of $G/C_{n-1}(G)$, and since this series has length $n-1$, that must be the class of $G/C_{n-1}(G)$.